# Storing settings of custom types

Tags: c#

I've used the settings system in .NET before for a winforms app. However, what I wonder is what if I need to store settings of a custom type? Could I edit the settings designer-generated class file?

I read a thread on here about doing this and it wasn't recommended (someone mentioned pressing F11 to open the file, or a similar key).

What can I do in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer generated class file will get lost on the next build.  You'll need to edit in the configuration view or in the xml file.

Depending on how much work you want to do, and what kind of behaviour you need, you can do something simple like manually defining a custom configuration section, with a simple wrapper class to access the settings.

On the other hand, there are tools like the [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) that can help...

Keep it as simple as you can though, especially if what you need to configure is relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my questions and will be useful for future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be dissuaded, it's not that hard.  Plus, the custom type you want to save will have a couple of properties on it, but when you add it to the application settings, you just configure 1 setting.  Here's how:

1. Update the settings.settings file.  Launch the settings designer and you'll see what you just added.  Don't worry, it won't get lost. - Just make sure to fully qualify your custom type like mynamspace.mycustomtype
2. Make your custom type [Serializable] – don’t forget to make the class and properties public

I created a custom type to save window settings.  With the following signature for the save settings method:

```
public void SaveSettings(Form aForm)
```

I was then able to use the following to save my custom type and its properties.  Notice that I use the Default[string] method instead of the designer created method like Default.MainForm

```
Properties.Settings.Default[aForm.Name] = this;  //Save my custom type
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```